# Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook Unable to create sheet while running automatically alone

Tags: java, unix, apache-poi

I'm doing an Automation of reading file arrival time from HDFS and populating the data in excel sheet for all the systems and colouring the timing if it crossed the threshold time.
I've done these using shell script and java for excel handling.
invoked the jar in shell script.
that shell script is being added in StartOftheDay.sh file to get triggered daily 5AM from CONTROL-M.
While running automatically like above, im getting below error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:662)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:679)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:90)
    at com.excel.ExcelReadWrite.convertCsvToXls(ExcelReadWrite.java:141)
    at com.excel.ExcelReadWrite.main(ExcelReadWrite.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
```

piece of java code causing this error,

```
    Workbook workBook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workBook.createSheet("Sheet1"); -- Here
```

piece of shell script from where jar is being invoked

```
java -jar /CTRLFW/CRR/prd/crr_strata/appl/sourcing/file_watcher/bin/Daily_Run/Scripts/CsvToExcel.jar $RUN_DATE $COLUMN_TO_APPEND
```

piece of shell script from where the above shell script is being called

```
nohup sh /CTRLFW/CRR/prd/crr_strata/appl/sourcing/file_watcher/bin/Daily_Run/Scripts/Prd_stats.sh $DAILY_STATUS_DATE >> /CTRLFW/CRR/prd/crr_strata/log/file_watcher/Daily_Run/${BATCH_ID}/Prd_stats.${BATCH_ID}.out &
```

above shell script is being called from CONTROL-M daily 5AM

**but if i run the above same command from the script manually its working perfectly as expected.**

help me with how to fix this.

Comment: What user account / permissions does the cron script run as? Could they be different to what a manual run executes as?

Comment: CONTROL-M trigger and manual triggger uses same userid.

Comment: Looks like either a JDK or configuration problem. Is your Java version updated? Log the value of `java.io.tmpdir`, check that the directory is writable by the user. Post the output of java -version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've set this "java.io.tmpdir" variable to one of the project folder in my shell script before calling the Java jar. It started working and running fine for the past 2 days,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set this "java.io.tmpdir" variable to one of the project folder in my shell script before calling the Java jar. It started working and running fine for the past 2 days

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/CTRLFW/CRR/prd/crr_strata/log/file_watcher/Daily_Run/temp/
```